# Melted distance table into distance matrix

Tags: dataframe, unix, awk

I have a table like this:

```
Var     score
1       1.00
1       1.06
1       1.03
1       0.65
1       0.68
2       1.06
2       1.07
2       0.64
2       1.05
3       0.71
3       0.72
3       1.03
4       0.68
4       1.08
5       0.11
```

Want to convert this into matrix like:

```
      1     2     3     4     5     6     
 1    0.00  1.00  1.06  1.03  0.65  0.68
 2    1.00  0.00  1.06  1.07  0.64  1.05
 3    1.06  1.06  0.00  0.71  0.72  1.03
 4    1.03  1.07  0.71  0.00  0.68  1.08
 5    0.65  0.64  0.72  0.68  0.00  0.11
 6    0.68  1.05  1.03  1.08  0.11  0.00
```

I tried awk but its keep running:

```
awk '{if(NF>max) max=NF} END{while(getline<"file"){for(i=NF+1;i<=max;i++)$i="0";print}}'
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts, mention what is the Logic for getting expected output in your question also to make it more clear(not my downvote).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It keeps running because you forgot to pass it the file name. So `awk` takes its input from the standard input and waits for you to enter something on the keyboard. Use `awk '...' file`, not just `awk '...'`. But even with this error fixed it will not work as you expect.

You don't need to read the file twice. You can build your matrix in one single pass and populate the missing cells in the `END` block (tested with GNU and BSD awk):

```
awk 'NR > 1 {
  num[$1] += 1
  mat[$1, $1 + num[$1]] = mat[$1 + num[$1], $1] = $2
  n = num[$1] > n ? num[$1] : n
}
END {
  n += 1
  mat[0, 0] = ""
  for(i = 1; i <= n; i += 1) {
    mat[0, i] = mat[i, 0] = i
    mat[i, i] = "0.00"
  }
  for(i = 0; i <= n; i += 1)
    for(j = 0; j <= n; j += 1)
      printf("%s%s", mat[i, j], j == n ? "\n" : "\t")
}' file
     1       2       3       4       5       6
1    0.00    1.00    1.06    1.03    0.65    0.68
2    1.00    0.00    1.06    1.07    0.64    1.05
3    1.06    1.06    0.00    0.71    0.72    1.03
4    1.03    1.07    0.71    0.00    0.68    1.08
5    0.65    0.64    0.72    0.68    0.00    0.11
6    0.68    1.05    1.03    1.08    0.11    0.00
```